# understanding of result of logistic regression

Tags: excel, regression, logistic-regression

let us suppose we have following data with binary response  output(coupon)

[image]

annual spending is given in 1000th  unit,  my goal is to estimate  whether if  customer spend more then 2000 and has Simmons card,  will also have  coupon, first of all i have  sorted data according  to  response data, i got following picture

[image]

at next stage i have calculated logit for each data, for  those initially i choose following  coefficient

```
B0  0.1
B1  0.1
B2  0.1
```

and i have calculated L   according to the following formula

[image]

at next stage i have calculated  e^L (which in excel  can be  done easily by exp function )

```
=EXP(D2)
```

after that i have calculated probability

```
=E2/(1+E2)
```

[image]

and finally using formula
[image]

i have calculated log likelihood function

then i have calculated sum and using solver i have calculated coefficient that minimize this sum( please pay attention that values are given in negative  value) , but i have got  all coefficient zero

[image]

i am  wrong ? or  does it means that   i can'predict buying of coupon on the base of Annual spending and  owning of Simmons card? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can predict the buying of a coupon on the base of Annual spending (and knowing Simmons card doesn't help).

Admittedly I didn't solve it in Excel, but I suspect the problem might be that your optimization didn't converge (i.e., failed to reach the correct coefficients through the solving process) -- the correct coefficients are B0 = 5.63, B1 = -2.95, and B2 = 0.  I found an online reference for the Excel logistic regression procedure at http://blog.excelmasterseries.com/2014/06/logistic-regression-performed-in-excel.html.

I ran the logistic regression myself and found that Annual spending is significant (at the 0.05 level) whereas Simmons card is not.  Re-running the model with Simmons card removed yields the following equations:

```
    L = 5.63 - 2.95 * Annual spending
    P(1)  =  exp(L)/(1 + exp(L))
    If P(1) > 0.5 => coupon = 1
```

Although the entropy Rsquare is low at 0.39 (and the number of data points is very low), the model is statistically significant.

Comment: thanks  my friend, i fixed  problem  , thanks for your help

Comment: My pleasure - glad it was helpful!